# formatting a proof justification with smaller font

Tags: formatting, fontsize

I need help formatting proof justifications. In the past, I have used `\quad\text{some short justification}.` Now, I have a longer justification -- still only one sentence but with the above approach it does not wrap around to the next page. Furthermore, how can I make the font smaller just for the justification.

Thanks for all the help.

**EDIT** The following is an example of what I do not want:

[image: justification that does not "line wrap" and goes off the page.]

The LaTeX code is:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  y &= x^8 +7x^6 - 5x^5 + 4x^3 - 9x^2 + 2x + 10000000 \\
    &= x^8 +7x^6 - 5x^5 + 4x^3 - 9x^2 + 2x + 9999999 + 1 \quad\text{by the craziest most difficult addition I have ever seen in my entire life!}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

When the justification "line-wraps" it would be nice for the second line to begin a few spaces indented from the start of the justification

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand your question. Could you explain it better and add a MWE also?

Comment: How can I show the results of latex code?

Comment: You have to compile it and since you use linux in a terminal is very easy to convert the pdf to a png file using imagemagick and later select the page you want to show us and upload it.

Answer (score 2):

For consistency sake, I would maintain the font size to be similar to the surrounding text (and math). You can make the contents wrap into multiple lines by using a `\parbox` of fixed width that is `[t]`op-aligned:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \quad \text{some short justification} \\
  g(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \quad \parbox[t]{.5\linewidth}{some longer justification that spans multiple lines}
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```